# Input geolocation Data in Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, dataset, data-preprocessing, gis, geography

I am working on a Neural Network that should predict certain transport-tariffs based on start and end region of the transport.
The region can take different forms, from a whole country to a range of zip codes or just from one zip code to another. When I feed my network the data I just extract the geocoordinates of the zip codes and use them to train the network. 
Is there a better form to input a geographical region to gain a better prediction?